# How to set exactly position another view when zoom or drag (left, right, up, down) image?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, position, zooming

I met a big trouble in this case.
I have a imageview (green icon) added on Image background. Green icon's position is set dynamically(Pic 1)

[image]

This Image can zoom in, zoom out, drag left, right, up, down. I want to to move exactly imageview's position (green icon) when zoom or drag image background.

How can I map imageview's position (green icon) with Image background when I zoom, drag Image background?

Picture 2: Image background is zoomed but green icon view does not map with image background, it's wrong position.

[image]

Can you suggest me some solution, direction or scripts. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

use following function which will overlay your image bitmap with mark image bitmap and return new bitmap which you can use to display

```
private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, float left, float top) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, left, top, null); 
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

eg :-

```
        Bitmap border = null;
        Bitmap scaledBorder = null;
        border = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.palette);
        scaledBorder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        im.setImageBitmap(overlay(border, scaledBorder, 0, 0));// replace both 0,0 point with your mark point
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got this code. It runs ok. But the problem is when I zoom new bitmap, the green icon is zoomed too. I don't want to zoom imageview icon. So, i have to divide 2 imageview instead of use a photo

Comment: Hello, i am finding similar question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625989/add-object-to-image-view-how-to-keep-object-location-when-zoom-image
    are  you have solution?